# How can I load database entries into my scala template?

Tags: database, scala, playframework

I am using play 2.3.8 and building a program where you can ask questions and answer them. I have several different users, so I use their unique email as the ID in the database.

Questions / answers have an ownerID, to show who has written them.

My users are stored in the DB like this:

```
Email           Name Password
bob@mail.com    Bob  secret
```

My questions are stored in the DB like this:

```
QUESTION_ID                             QUESTION_TEXT       VOTE_SCORE      OWNER_ID        PAGE  
77b7f88a-41df-4d68-9f89-de508fce8f71    How tall is tall?   1228            bob@mail.com    1
```

My controller class, that collects the questions / answers from the DB and sends the lists to the view class:

```
public static List<Question> questionListAll = new ArrayList<Question>();
public static List<Answer> answerListAll = new ArrayList<Answer>();

public static Result index() {
        questionListAll.clear();
        answerListAll.clear();

        // Get all questions from DB
        for (Question questionItem : Question.find.all()) {
            questionListAll.add(questionItem);
        }

        // Get all answers from DB
        for (Answer answerItem : Answer.find.all()) {
            answerListAll.add(answerItem);
        }

        Collections.sort(questionListAll, Collections.reverseOrder());
        Collections.sort(answerListAll, Collections.reverseOrder());

        return ok(views.html.index.render(questionListAll, answerListAll));
    }
```

User.java:

```
// FIXME Dont really save the password as String...
@Id
public String email;
public String name;
public String password;
(...)
```

Question.java:

```
@Entity
public class Question extends Model implements Comparable<Question> {
    @Id
    public String questionID;
    public String questionText;
    public Integer voteScore;
    public String ownerID;
    public Integer page;
(...)
}
```

In my view class I show the questions and behind them the user by using `@answer.ownerID` ... but as I use the email-field as ID, the entry is something like:

`"How tall is tall?" - bob@mail.com`

What I want is:

`"How tall is tall?" - Bob Ross` (using their name and not their email)

I know I could simply find all questions and their owners in my controller and put the users into another list, from where I would use `@users.username`, but this would mean I always have to look up all users, put them into the list, ...

So is it possible to look into the DB, use the ownerID and get the username in the view class?

Or more general: Can you look up DB entries for the view class from the view class itself?

Comment: How do you have the users' names stored in relation to the email?

Comment: What you are looking for are SQL join operations. How do you fetch  answers from the db? It would be helpful if you post some code what you have so far. (+1 for Bob Ross)

Comment: @nbz: I have added how I store my users in the DB, does this help you?

Comment: @Roman: I have added my code. I did omit my code as my question is more general and I did not want to confuse. 
You mean something like ScalaAnorm? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm

Comment: ScalaAnorm is actually just an abstraction layer to simplify access to the underlying database system. Assuming you are using Ebean I cannot really help you out here. I'm sure someone will pick up this question. In the meantime it might be a good idea to read about sql, especially sql querying and joins.

Comment: I put a bounty up, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add mappings with JPA 2.0 to achieve what you want in your view, then you may use `@question.owner.name` or `@answer.owner.name`.

> User.java

```
[...]
@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
public Long userId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Question> questionList;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Answer> answerList;
[...]
```

> Question.java

```
[...]
@Id
@Column(name="question_id")
public Long questionId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
public User owner;

// @OneToMany: ORM join relationship, one Question to many Answers
// FetchType.LAZY: ORM will not fetch from db until you use it
// CascadeType.ALL: any changes to question will be propagated
//   onQuestionDelete: all answers associated with the question will be deleted
//   onQuestionUpdateAnswerList: any updates made will reflect on db
// mappedBy: Question object variable name on Answer object for ORM to make a connection
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Answer> answerList;
[...]
```

> Answer.java

```
[...]
@Id
@Column(name="answer_id")
public Long answerId;

// FetchType.EAGER: ORM will fetch this from db when Answer is fetch
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
public User owner;

// @ManyToOne: ORM join relationship, many Question to one Answer
// @JoinColumn: name, pk column name of Question; nullable false, required constraint;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="question_id", nullable = false)
public Question question;
[...]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I seem to have not formulated my question precise enough, so I added my classes. Nonetheless your answer helps me to find the correct direction, but could you explain some of the lines so I understand it better and might fit it to my problem?
Especially the fetch- and cascade-lines, why do you do it this way?

Comment: Updated my answer with comments. For fetch, we want to control WHEN our objects are queried by JPA like for User we use Fetch.LAZY so that it will not be queried instantly thus saving us resources while on Question and Answer we need Fetch.EAGER since we will be using it for the view. And if ever you need Question's answerList to be served in view, since its lazy loaded, you need to use its getters for the query to kick in and serve it in your view. For cascade, we used it to propagate the db operation used in the parent to the child accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand more or less whats going on.